# Can we do a switch case with an in clause

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

Can we do use an in clause with case

```
sql_query=f"""SELECT * FROM table1
where column1 in ('{list_of_values}')
order by CASE
WHEN column2 like'a%' THEN 1
WHEN column2 like'b%' THEN 2
WHEN column2 like'c%' THEN 3
ELSE 99 END;
"""
```

I am not getting any value in return but when I try

```
sql_query=f"""SELECT * FROM table1
where column1 = '{value1}'
order by CASE
WHEN column2 like'a%' THEN 1
WHEN column2 like'b%' THEN 2
WHEN column2 like'c%' THEN 3
ELSE 99 END;
"""
```

I get a value in return. What am I doing wrong in the first query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
where column1 in ('{list_of_values}')
```

your `'{list_of_values}'` isn't going to work, it needs to be each individual item comma separated and within individual quotes e.g. `where column1 in ('a','b','c','etc')`